# Cannot start PostgreSQL: postgresql-upgrade is missing

Tags: fedora, yum, postgresql

Yesterday I upgraded my Fedora from 19 to 20. And now I cannot start PostgreSQL because of old database format. The steps are:

1.

```
# systemctl start postgresql

Job for postgresql.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

2.

```
# journalctl -xn

postgresql-check-db-dir[30869]: An old version of the database format was found.                                                                                                                             
postgresql-check-db-dir[30869]: Use "postgresql-setup upgrade" to upgrade to version 9.3.                                                                                                                    
postgresql-check-db-dir[30869]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql/README.rpm-dist for more information.                                                                                                          
postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1                                                                                                                                 
systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

3.

```
#postgresql-setup upgrade                                

Please install the postgresql-upgrade RPM.
```

4.

```
#yum install postgresql-upgrade

Загружены модули: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit                                                                                  
pgdg93   |   3.6 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates   |   3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo   |   2.7 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates   |   3.3 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo   |   2.7 kB  00:00:00     
updates/20/x86_64/metalink   |   28 kB  00:00:00     
updates-debuginfo/20/x86_64/metalink   |   24 kB  00:00:00     
pgdg93/20/x86_64/primary_db   |   77 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64/primary_db  

Package postgresql-upgrade not found.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is repo too old?

Comment: Please show `rpm -qi postgresql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked my local Fedora mirror and the postgresql-upgrade RPM is certainly present in the Fedora 20 and 21 repos.

```
/srv/www/mirrors/fedora/releases/20/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/postgresql-upgrade-9.3.1-2.fc20.x86_64.rpm
/srv/www/mirrors/fedora/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/postgresql-upgrade-9.3.5-4.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

So I suspect you've hit a bad or out-of-sync mirror site. You can run `yum clean all` and try again to see if you get a different mirror site.

This may also be caused by your having the `pgdg93` repository installed. Since Fedora already has PostgreSQL 9.3, there seems little point to having this, and its packages are probably causing conflict.